# Shell Commands: Identical Parameters, Different Values

Tags: shell

In Bash and other shells, many commands can take parameters that do different things (in reality, the "commands" are files, but bear with me here). For example, with `mongod -f ~/mongo.conf --quiet --port 8070 --bind_ip 127.0.0.2 --dbpath ~/data/db --ipv6`, we are calling the `mongod` command (actually the `mongod` or `mongod.exe` file somewhere in the system's PATH) with the parameters `-f ~/mongo.conf`, which has the Mongo daemon use the configuration file at `~/mongo.conf`; `--quiet`, which suppresses error and other messages; `--port 8070`, which has the server use port 8070; `--bind_ip 127.0.0.2`, which has the server use IP address 127.0.0.2; `--dbpath ~/data/db`, which has Mongo store its databases at `~/data/db`, and `--ipv6`, which has Mongo broadcast on IPv6 as well as IPv4.

What I am asking is how do shells usually deal with commands using multiple parameters which are identical but where the user inputs different values for each copy? Does the shell use the first or last copy or something in the middle? Does it even allow multiple identical parameters? For example, if I try to run the command (again, technically file) `npm ls --depth 0 --depth 2 --depth 6 --depth 2`, to tell the `npm` package manager how many levels deep to list dependencies from at the maximum, would it list dependencies a maximum of 0, 2 or 6 levels deep? Or would it tell me to go away and stop wasting its time with frivolities?

I am mainly asking this question for UNIX-based shells like bash, sh, csh, and dash, but would welcome information about other shells like cmd and Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "What I am asking is how do shells usually deal with commands using
>   multiple parameters"

As an example:

```
npm ls --depth 0 --depth 2 --depth 6 --depth 2
```

The shell sees this as a command name, `npm`, followed by nine arguments.  The shell does not know or care what those arguments are or that a human might be confused by those various different values "depth".  The shell merely takes those nine strings and passes them as arguments to `npm`.  The interpretation of those values is entirely up to the code in the executable.

Some executables might return an error message.  Some may assume that later values override earlier.  Whatever it does, it is up to the whim of the person who programmed that executable.  This should all be specified in the documentation for the command, not the shell.

Comment: So it's based on the shell script, not the shell itself? I guess that makes more sense. Shell scripting is so interesting in its "low-level-ness" - like how the command in my question/your answer has 9 parameters, not 1 sub-command and 4 parameters.

Comment: @trysis Yes, it is based on the executable, whether it is a shell script or something else, and not the shell.